# scrollIntoView() is not a function upon page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of FAQ's where I've hidden the answers by default, leaving only the question, and I've provided a link to each particular question by embedding an id anchor in each so others can link to it.

The question format structure is as follows:

```
<div class="contents">
   <h1 class="question" id="titleOfQuestion">Some Question Title</h1>
   <div class="answer" id="titleOfQuestion">>
      Some Answer
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to scroll the question into view upon page load if there's an ID anchor in the URL because `div.contents` is of a fixed height and often overflows with the property `scroll`.

Wrapped in a document ready handler, the following code does not work:

```
if(document.location.hash) {
var id = document.location.hash.substring(1);
    $('div#' + id).scrollIntoView();
}
```

And I receive the error in Firebug: `TypeError: $(...).scrollIntoView is not a function`. However, if I then reload the URL from the same location, it **does** work.

What's going on here?

Comment: why you are putting same id titleOfQuestion in the H1 and the Div.answer both?

Comment: Because they're semantically related and it makes sense to provide some sort of link between them.

Comment: still, you are not allowed to keep same to multiple elements. Javascript doesnt work like that.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView) is part of the DOM API, not jQuery. You need to run it on an Element, not a jQuery object:

```
$('div#' + id)[0].scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I've tried this too, and I get the same result from all browsers. Upon page load, I no longer get an `undefined` message, but it still simply doesn't work.

Comment: Are you doing this in a `$(document).ready` callback, to insure the DOM is ready to be accessed?

Comment: Yup, wrapped in a document ready handler. This method also acts similarly to above. The initial URL load won't trigger `scrollIntoView()`, but then if I reload it in the browser, `scrollIntoView()` *will* work.

Comment: I was doing same mistake of running it on jQuery object. This worked for me. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question because scrollIntoView() does not work on DOMContentLoaded or whatever other method you're using to check if the DOM is ready/page is loaded. I couldn't find any documentation/comments anywhere to find out why scrollIntoView() doesn't work on page load. However I was able to work around it using a slightly more expensive but reliable option by doing this - `window.scrollTo({top: document.querySelector('.your-selector-here').offsetTop, behavior: 'smooth' });`

Answer (score 6):

[Test](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/scrollintoview.html)

```
var x = document.getElementById('test');
x.scrollIntoView();
```

see also this [plugin](https://github.com/Arwid/jQuery.scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so here is a solution example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="view1">
    <i onclick="gotoView(1)">View 1</i> | <i onclick="gotoView(2)">View 2</i> | <i onclick="gotoView(3)">View 3</i>
</div>
<div id="view2">
    <i onclick="gotoView(1)">View 1</i> | <i onclick="gotoView(2)">View 2</i> | <i onclick="gotoView(3)">View 3</i>
</div>
<div id="view3">
    <i onclick="gotoView(1)">View 1</i> | <i onclick="gotoView(2)">View 2</i> | <i onclick="gotoView(3)">View 3</i>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{height:800px; margin:20px; background:#CCC; text-align:center}
i{cursor:pointer; display:inline-block}
i:hover{background:#C00}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function gotoView(viewId){
    document.getElementById("view" + viewId).scrollIntoView();
    window.location.hash = "view" + viewId;
}
```

Try this to understand it better.